# Rcpp: porting C++ function into R, 'Rcpp.h' file not found

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have some C++ code. I would like to make this an R package with Rcpp.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create a package framework by executing `Rcpp.package.skeleton("myPackageName")`
2. Run `devtools::load_all()` to see whether `rcpp_hello_world()` works after `library(myPackageName)`. It does!
3. Take all C++ source code and copy this into `/src`. I can still use `rcpp_hello_world()` after running `devtools::load_all()` once again.
4. For each function in the C++ source code now residing in `/src`, simply do this:

(A) Put at the top of the `.cpp` file `

```
 #include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
```

(B) Put before each function `void` this comment

```
 //[[Rcpp::export]]
```

Now, I foolishly think that if I run `devtools::load_all()`, the code with compile and those C++ functions will be accessible. This is incorrect.

Here's the error after `load_all()`:

```
 1 warning generated.
sourcecode1.cc:2:10: fatal error: 'Rcpp.h' file not found
#include <Rcpp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [myPackageName] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘myPackageName’
```

It cannot find the header file `Rcpp.h`

(1) Is my procedure above incorrect in creating R packages directly from C++ code with Rcpp? This is what I've gathered from the book

(2) How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run 'compileAttributes()'  which RStudio would do for you too.

In short each time you alter or add interfaces,  you need to run this function.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the response. (1) Within the package directory, I've run `library(Rcpp)`, `compileAttributes(pkgdir = ".", verbose = getOption("verbose"))`, and `devtools::load_all()`. I get the same error as above. 2. This would be easier in RStudio?

Comment: Check that you have updated files RcppExports. R and RcppExports.cpp as a result.  The next rebuild will then reflect them.   And for what it is worth I do not use devtools myself.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You're right! The functions are there in ` RcppExports.R` and `RcppExports.cpp`. So, it's `'compileAttributes()` which places them there. Question: "And for what it is worth I do not use devtools myself"
Then how would I "load" my package so I can then use it? That is, `library(myPackageName)` and call the functions?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel @Coatless I guess `install(myPackageName)`? I'm just suspicious that `load_all()` is failing...

Comment: Well screw `devtools` if it confuses you!!  Do 1) `compileAttributes()` (and I have a helper script `compAttr.r` in littler that does it), then 2) run `./cleanup` to make sure everything will get rebuilt and 3) `R CMD INSTALL .` and it should all work.  Been using the workflow since day one, as the saying goes "it works for me".  I *think* there are more Rcpp helpers in `devtools` but I am not the person to ask...

Comment: I'm more of a `CNTRL` + `SHIFT` + `B` fella with RStudio. Otherwise, I default to Dirk's method (minus littler!). Though, the following is perhaps a way to use `devtools` outside of `load_all()`: 1. `compileAttributes()`, 2. `build()`, and 3. `install()`. (Assuming working directory is package root.)

Comment: I use Ctrl-Shift-B at times as well.  One also needs to (one-time) set project options correctly.  Including to turn off `devtools` in my case ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!